# How to retrieve the parent frame name by its element

Tags: javascript

I got the reference of element inside the frame by dom click event, How do i know its frame name.

```
function eventTrigger(evt){ 
     alert(evt.target.name);    //Need to know frame name of evt.target 
}

frame.addEventListener("click", eventTrigger);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to check this:

```js
function eventTrigger(evt){ 
     // alert(evt.target.name);    
     console.dir(evt.target);
}

frame.addEventListener("click", eventTrigger);
```

You can see on the console panel all the properties of the element. If it has a name you can target the name with `evt.target.name` but you have to set it on the html. A class or an id could be useful in this situation too.

`evt.target.classList`or `evt.target.id`

[image]